# Change username and password (if possible remotely) with, for example, Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, passwords

I'm trying to find a way to change the username and password in Windows 7 for my computer and a friend in my network to do some research and testing in my class.

I've found that using Windows Powershell it's possible, but I find websites with some script lines, I write and customize them to change or create user accounts with usernames and password and I'm not able.

So question is simple:

How to change username and password in Windows Powershell remotely, for example, sending a script from server to client.

Regards,
Cristobal.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already so that we can fill in the blanks. If nothing else I would hope you ran into this a [resource](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/03/25/how-can-i-change-the-passwords-of-multiple-local-computer-accounts.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No need for the powershell, could be just a simple batch file. Execute the following from the command prompt to change teh password: net user user_name new_password

You have to be logged in as administrator